# Responsive height div cells in table with row span

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Hi this is probably easier to explain with an image. I'm using foundation 6 to make a layout with a banner. The layout looks like this:

[image]

The issue I have is that I don't know how to do a pure CSS solution to get box 1, 2, 3 etc a third (with margins) of the responsive image. I can do it no problem with a few lines of jquery but I can't help but think this isn't really the best / fastest solution.

Like I said i'm using foundation 6 so happy to use flexbox to get it sorted if that's a way of doing it but so far my experimentation has failed.

I can post the code I have so far but I don't think it's particularly helpful since getting a layout like this easy it's just the height on the grey boxes doesn't extend the full height.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to have space between image and boxes?

Comment: @Morven Yeah definitely need the margins I'm afraid. I guess they could come from a white border? Obviously I intend on vertically centring the text in those "box" divs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- General

  - [viewport measurements](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design) `vw` `vh`
  - [percentage measurements](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-units/)
- The outer container:

  - [`display: table`](https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=background)
  - [`min-width: fit-content`](http://thenewcode.com/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent)
- Left

  - [`background-image` `background-repeat`](https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=background) (in shorthand)
  - [`background-size`](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)
  - [`display: table-cell`](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)
- Right is [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)

  - `display: flex`
  - `flex-flow: row wrap`
  - `align-content: space-between`

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>flexSeries3</title>
<style>
#main { min-width: -moz-fit-content; min-width: -webkit-fit-content; min-width: fit-content; height: auto; overflow: hidden; display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
.iImg { width: 49vw; height: 96vh; display: table-cell; background: url(https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/xH2LQ-c4CZJp6X-Iv27s7kvDRts=/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4106218/GettyImages-489748146_master.0.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center; outline: 3px ridge #999; }
.iFlex { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; align-items: center; align-content: space-between; width: 49vw; height: 96vh; background: #fff; }
.fBox { width: 48%; height: 32%; background: #777; margin: 1%; }
.fFoot { width: 98%; height: 32%; background: #777; margin: 1%; }
#f1 { order: 1; }
#f2 { order: 2; }
#f3 { order: 3; }
#f4 { order: 4; }
#f5 { order: 5; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<main id="main">
<section class="iImg">
</section>
<section class="iFlex">
<div id="f1" class="fBox">1</div>
<div id="f2" class="fBox">2</div>
<div id="f3" class="fBox">3</div>
<div id="f4" class="fBox">4</div>
<div id="f5" class="fFoot">5</div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, just running your snippet looks that's exactly what I need. I'm about to wrap up or the day but I'll give this a go in the morning. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, happy to oblige.

Comment: I can't up vote just yet but you'd be getting one if i could :)

Comment: Thank you, sir and happy coding ;-)